# What is the best way to optimize a massive CouchDB database?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have a CouchDB instance running on AWS (m4.large EC2 on CentOS) which is in excess of 75GB in size and constantly growing. I have encountered problems when modifying and indexing views on this database, which is taking almost 2 days now.

What are the optimization strategies available to me to make sure that:

1. Re-indexing after a map-reduce view change can be done more
   efficiently
2. Fetching from a map-reduce view can be done faster (with
   a custom reduce function in place)

I've read the suggestions on the [CouchDB guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html), but they're targeted more towards optimizing inserts.

Comment: Have you been able to successfully manage couchdb at this scale eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have such a large database, it does take time to re-index views when one is changed, it will not be near instant like it is when you have a smaller database. Now that I have said that, here is a solution for #1.

Whenever a design document is updated, it re-indexes all views within that document, so having each view in its own design document may increase some re-index speed. Since you do have a massive database, it will still take time to go through every document and re-index them, just now it will do one view and not all views.

Edit: Links
[CouchDB Views Intro](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/ddocs/views/intro.html) -> This is the overview of the CouchDB views documentation. I've read and re-read this page multiple times and always find something new each time. I suggest reading it over a few times just to be sure.

[CouchDB One vs Multiple Design Documents](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/ddocs/views/intro.html#one-vs-multiple-design-documents) -> Same page, but it will bring you to the section about my answer above. Please give it a read through and I hope it helps.

I do not know how to address #2, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I've seen those docs but I'll follow your recommendation and go through them again.